# jinja2 can not read self

Tags: google-app-engine, jinja2

I have been using django for a while and I am now converting to jinja2 because GAE told me too. One of the short cuts I use for django is to pass "self" to django when rendering my template so that in my template I call {{ self.stuff }}. In jinja it seems that "self" represents something. Does this require me to change all my templates to use perhaps "this"?

Comment: `self` in general is not a right word to use in your situation so definitely change it to `name-of-obj` or just `obj`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self` is actually used by Jinja2 to allow you to reference blocks:

```
<!-- In your layout.html file -->
<title>{%- block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
<!-- Some distance further down ... -->
<h1>{{self.title()}}</h1>

<!-- In a file that extends layout.html -->
{% block title %}The Title of the Page{% endblock %}

<!-- The above will render -->
<title>The Title of the Page</title>
<!-- Some other stuff ... -->
<h1>The Title of the Page</h1>
```

Simply use another name and everything will work (i.e., rather than `self` use `this` or `obj` as suggested by @Skirmantas).